# populate an excel template with data from different Sharepoint views

Tags: sharepoint-2010, excel, vba

I am very new to Sharepoint and apologize for being very vague.

I have an excel template that is filled with data by exporting different views from the sharepoint site. I am trying to automate the whole process so that the user has to only export the view and the template gets filled with required data automatically (and would prefer to completely by-pass the step to export).So the workflow is like this:

```
1. Select a view from the sharepoint site
2. Export the view using "Export to Spreadsheet" option
3. Save or open the .iqy file
4. Repeat the steps 1-3 for 2 more different views
```

Now that I have the data that I need, I can start filling that data by looking the Project name and its corresponding data in export 2 and 3. All the views have the Project Name in common. I have to get the Risks name from export 2 and Completed Activities and Upcoming Activities from export 3 for a Project.

Task: What I need is that my template should have a dropdown that is populated by retrieving the project name from the Sharepoint view, and puts data in Risks and Activities and other placeholders and adjust the number of rows as different Projects will have different number of Risks and Activities items.

Any direction to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me suggest 2 options:

1. Create an Excel add-on and use the Sharepoint client-object model
2. Create a custom Sharepoint Web Part with the required UI. Use Sharepoint Server Object Model to retrieve the data. Use the Open XML SDK to create the Excel.

You can google any of the technologies listed above and you will find plenty of info.

But a short summary: SP Client Model is a way of accessing Sharepoint from outside the Sharepoint Server (it works with webservices in the background) and the Sharepoint Server Model is a way of accessing Sharepoint from the server. The Open XML SDK is a way of accessing/creating Office documents without the need of having office installed on the server. It is based on XML.

Comment: Thank you very much providing some direction. I am new to developing add-ons but will learn how to develop one. Sharepoint web-part is out-of-scope as I have neither the access to Sharepoint nor the expertise. I have no programming experience in Sharepoint.

If you can provide some direction on the first option, that will be great! Thank you again...

Comment: Please note that you would still need knowledge of Sharepoint client Object Model. Refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg277498.aspx.

Comment: for excel add-in please refer to here: http://www.google.com.mt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc668205.aspx&ei=M1pOUICRBYeE4gTB-ID4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEo9TAXmDTgxiUn8qO87m3E-v-raA

Comment: also, please note that the options I am suggesting are not simple, so I cannot give you detailed answers. You would have to research technologies yourself. Thanks

Comment: And also, please carry out a proof of concept study to make sure it meets your requirements